# Text Processing using sed/awk/perl

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, aix

I have a text like this pattern on many lines. Can I group only the values and the name into a single line?

```
ABCDEFG_10_node10:2154  ABCDEFG_10_node10:54
ABCDEFG_10_node10:2254  ABCDEFG_10_node10:64
ABCDEFG_10_node10:410 ABCDEFG_10_node10:10
ABCDEFG_10_node10:210 ABCDEFG_10_node10:10 
ABCDEFG_10_node10:365
ABCDEFG_10_node10:890
ABCDEFG_10_node10:741
XXYZZ_71_node2:24: XXYZZ_71_node2:504:
X3y5z_53_node1:664: X3y5z_53_node1:990:
RCTY_11_node2:224: RCTY_11_node2:234:
```

Output expected:

```
ABCDEFG_10_node10: 2154,2254,410,210,365,890,741,54,64,10,10
XXYZZ_71_node2: 24,504
X3y5z_53_node1: 664,990
RCTY_11_node2: 224,234
```

I’m on AIX. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you specifically insist on that order,  or would 2154,54,2254,64,410,10,210,10,365,890,741 be acceptable?

Comment: any order is acceptable scott.

Comment: @satsensort, you have added some content to your input. Does it really contain trailing semicolons after some values `XXYZZ_71_node2:24: `, `X3y5z_53_node1:990:`? or it's just a typo?

Comment: Please make sure your examples accurately represent your file. Your new data have the extra `:` and also extra whitespace. Do we need to deal with that as well?

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 5):

A Perl approach (assuming the order isn't important):

```
$ perl -lne 'while(/(\w+):(\d+)/g){
                push @{$k{$1}},$2
             } 
             END{
                print "$_: " . join ",", @{$k{$_}} for keys %k
             }' file 
ABCDEFG_10_node10: 2154,54,2254,64,410,10,210,10,365,890,741
```

That reads the input file line by line (`-ln`) and runs the script given by `-e` on it. The `while(/(\w+):(\d+)/g)` will collect all instances of non-whitespace, followed by a `:` and then more non-whitespace. Since they are being captured in parentheses, the `$1` will be the name and the `$2` the value. These are then pushed into a hash of arrays (hash `%k`, whose values are arrays). Finally, we print each key of the hash (the names) along with the array of its values, joined by `,`.

If you value conciseness, you can do write the above as a one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'while(/(\S+):(\S+)/g){push @{$k{$1}},$2}}{$"=",";print"$_: @{$k{$_}}" for keys%k' file
```

pushed past legibility:

```
perl -nE'push@{$k{$1}},$2while/(\w+):(\d+)/g}{$"=",";say"$_: @{$k{$_}}"for keys%k' file
```

Answer (score 3):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' '{ 
         a[$1]=a[$1]? a[$1]","$2:$2; if(NF==4) b[$3]=b[$3]? b[$3]","$4:$4 
     }
     END{ for(i in a) printf "%s: %s%s\n",i,a[i],(i in b)? ","b[i]:"" }' file
```

---

- `-F':|[[:space:]]+'` - complex field separator
- `a[$1]=a[$1]? a[$1]","$2:$2` - grouping values for each unique name `ABCDEFG...`
- `if(NF==4) b[$3]=b[$3]? b[$3]","$4:$4` - if there is an additional right-side section - group values into additional array `b`

---

The output:

```
ABCDEFG_10_node10: 2154,2254,410,210,365,890,741,54,64,10
```

**----------**

If the order of values isn't important the above approach could be slightly simplified:

```
awk -F':|[[:space:]]+' '{ 
        a[$1]=a[$1]? a[$1]","$2:$2; if(NF==4) a[$3]=a[$3]? a[$3]","$4:$4 
     }
     END{ for(i in a) print i":",a[i] }' file
```

Comment: @satsensort, you're welcome

Comment: You may be able to simplify the awk by formatting the input to one column: `fmt -w 1 input | sed 's/:$//' | awk ...` (I also stripped off the trailing colon characters)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { split($NF,arr,":");if (dat[arr[1]]=="") { dat[arr[1]]=arr[2] } else { dat[arr[1]]=dat[arr[1]]","arr[2] } } } END { for ( i in dat ) { print i": "dat[i] } }' filename
```

An alternative awk solution to Roman's where we take each space delimited piece of data in turn and then further split the data using the split function in the array arr based on the character : We then build an array keyed on the ABC etc string with the string of numbers to be printed. We then loop through this array (dat) building a string starting with the key along with : and the string. This is then printed.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e 'say .key, " => ", .value.words[1,3,5...*] for lines.split(/<[:\s]>/, :skip-empty).rotor(2).classify( *.[0]);'
```

Sample Input:

```
ABCDEFG_10_node10:2154  ABCDEFG_10_node10:54
ABCDEFG_10_node10:2254  ABCDEFG_10_node10:64
ABCDEFG_10_node10:410 ABCDEFG_10_node10:10
ABCDEFG_10_node10:210 ABCDEFG_10_node10:10 
ABCDEFG_10_node10:365
ABCDEFG_10_node10:890
ABCDEFG_10_node10:741
XXYZZ_71_node2:24: XXYZZ_71_node2:504:
X3y5z_53_node1:664: X3y5z_53_node1:990:
RCTY_11_node2:224: RCTY_11_node2:234:
```

Sample Output:

```
XXYZZ_71_node2 => (24 504)
RCTY_11_node2 => (224 234)
ABCDEFG_10_node10 => (2154 54 2254 64 410 10 210 10 365 890 741)
X3y5z_53_node1 => (664 990)
```

Briefly, `lines` are read in, destructively `split` on `:` and `\s` (omitting any empty elements via `:skip-empty`), `rotor` (join) every 2 elements, and `classify`-ing by the first of each pair. [I could make the call `.classify( *.[0].unique)` to clarify the intent, but Raku does the right thing either way].

If the OP really wants the format specified in his/her post, then substitute `=>` with `:`  and add a call to `join` at the end of the `.value` call, so the whole section prior to `for` reads: `say .key, ": ", .value.words[1,3,5...*].join(",")`

Sample Output (2):

```
X3y5z_53_node1: 664,990
RCTY_11_node2: 224,234
ABCDEFG_10_node10: 2154,54,2254,64,410,10,210,10,365,890,741
XXYZZ_71_node2: 24,504
```

https://docs.raku.org/routine/classify
https://raku.org